# CKEditor: configuring allowed content in DjangoCMS

Tags: javascript, python, ckeditor, django-cms

I have a problem with configuring CKeditor. I want to make "How to Allow Everything Except..." scheme in CKEditor, and as written in docs, I need write in config:

```
config.allowedContent = {
    $1: {
        // Use the ability to specify elements as an object.
        elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
        attributes: true,
        styles: true,
        classes: true
    }
};
config.disallowedContent = 'script; *[on*]';
```

But since config of CKEditor written in python, I can't simply write `CKEDITOR.dtd`. So, is there any solution or not?

Answer (score 0):

For many situations it might be enough to add additional allowed tags or attributes using the following declarations in your `settings.py`:

```
TEXT_ADDITIONAL_TAGS = ('iframe',)
TEXT_ADDITIONAL_ATTRIBUTES = ('scrolling', 'allowfullscreen', 'frameborder')
```

Of course, you will need to adjust to your needs.

If you really want your "allow everything but" logic, you will have to write your own parser for the backend which Django CMS uses to sanitize the HTML. This means, on the frontend editor that you might want to turn off all sanitation using the options

```
CKEDITOR_SETTINGS = {
    ...,
    'basicEntities': False,
    'entities': False,
    ...
}
```

On the backend side, the [documentation](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-text-ckeditor#user-content-configurable-sanitizer) states you can write your own python parser that will fit your requirement. I have not tried this so please let me know if that was of any help.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add style attribute to the anchor link (ex: `style="background-image: url('static/img/slide-1.jpg');"`).
The editor was emptying the style attribute when saved.
I have tried the below settings.

```
CKEDITOR_SETTINGS = {
    ...,
    'basicEntities': False,
    'entities': False,
    ...
}
```

But, it didn't work.

I had to completely disable the feature, set `TEXT_HTML_SANITIZE = False`.

It worked for me.